# Beam/Dataflow stateful processing, ParDo never runs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I'm trying to use Beam's stateful processing on Dataflow, but I get these errors in the log every time I try to output data. The result is that nothing is outputted from the stateful `ParDo`+`DoFn`:

```
16:45:56.948 CEST Proposing dynamic split of work unit myproject;2020-03-31_07_34_07-7523868393961495218;8536385410242733529 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5}
16:45:56.948 CEST Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

**Edit** This seems be coincidental. It *seems* like the stateful `ParDo` doesn't output any elements until the window fires. Is this correct?

This example replicates the error with Scio's `.batchByKey` (it's using stateful processing under the hood):

```
    val create = Create.of(()).withCoder(CoderMaterializer.beam(sc, Coder[Unit]))
    sc.customInput("Unit input", create)
      .map(_ => println("STARTING"))
      .applyTransform(ParDo.of(new Increasing)) // Outputs infinite stream of increasing numbers, one per second, prints each number to stdout
      .keyBy(1 -> _)
      .batchByKey(5)
      .map {
        case (key, vs) => vs.foreach(v => println(s"GOT batch with $v"))
      }
    sc.run()
```

The final `.map`, which is just a `ParDo`+`DoFn` with a single output, never runs.

In the output I see five lines of increasing numbers (from `new Increasing`) followed by the two messages above. This repeats.

Anyone know what the error may be? This seems to be the source [apache/beam/../WorkerCustomSources.java#L698](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/worker/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/worker/WorkerCustomSources.java#L698)

Answer (score 0):

That error simply means that a source that you are using in your pipeline cannot be split. So it's not directly related to progress of your pipeline but might be related in this case. The only source I see you using is `Create` and your issue could potentially be due to your `Create` being initialized with an empty tuple. Can try seeding your pipeline with a `Create` that has one or more elements.

Comment: Agree, it seems coincidental. Do you know how stateful processing relates to windows? Will a stateful ParDo only output when the window fires?

Comment: I think firing depends on windowing/triggering mechanism you have setup. Not on whether your ParDo is stateful or not. I think the issue here might be your Create transform being empty.